# Changing iCloud email

Tags: icloud, email

I need to change the iCloud email address associated with my iCloud. I can't update any apps. I can't check the current email address as its no longer active. How do I change it?

Comment: ... all the old apps & the pad itself will still belong to the old ID.

Answer (score -1):

1. Open the `Settings` app on your iPad
2. Go to the `iCloud` tab
3. Scroll down, tap `Sign Out`.
4. In your case, tap `Delete from my device`, then  enter your password.

To get a new iCloud account on your iPad, go to back to the `iCloud` menu, then sign in by following the setup prompts.